# Functional JavaScript: Produce array of unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

What is the way of producing an array of unique values out of another array using functional programming in JavaScript?

This should do: `toUnique([1,1,2,3,4,4]) => [1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked and answered 1000 times before, but since you're asking for a functional programming solution, here you go:

```
head  = function(ls)  { return ls[0] };
tail  = function(ls)  { return ls.slice(1) };
empty = function(ls)  { return ls.length == 0 };
cons  = function(a, b) { return [a].concat(b) };

has = function(x, ls) {
    return empty(ls) ? false : head(ls) == x || has(x, tail(ls));
};

_uniq = function(ls, seen) {
    return empty(ls) ? [] :
        has(head(ls), seen) ?
            _uniq(tail(ls), seen) :
            cons(head(ls),
                _uniq(tail(ls),
                    cons(head(ls), seen)));
};

uniq = function(ls) {
    return _uniq(ls, []);
};

console.log(uniq([1,1,2,3,1,2,5])); // [1,2,3,5]
```

This is pure functional solution, as requested (in fact, a straight port of [`nub`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.1/docs/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/Data-List.html#nub)). For a *practical* one, consider one of the answers [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array/9229821).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [uniq](http://ramdajs.com/docs/R.html#uniq) function of the [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/index.html) functional javascript libriary.

```
R.uniq([1, 1, 2, 1]); //=> [1, 2]
R.uniq([{}, {}]);     //=> [{}, {}]
R.uniq([1, '1']);     //=> [1, '1']
```

You can use the function from libriary or check the [source code](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/uniq.js)...

```
function uniq(list) {
    var idx = -1, len = list.length;
    var result = [], item;
    while (++idx < len) {
        item = list[idx];
        if (!_contains(item, result)) {
            result[result.length] = item;
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: This one is great! Is there any FRP lib with same amount of functions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are not worried about the performance, I would use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), like this

```
function toUnique(array) {
    return array.filter(function(currentItem, index) {
        return (index === array.indexOf(currentItem));
    });
}

console.log(toUnique([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]));
# [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

If you can use any other libraries, you can use [lodash's `uniq` function](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq), like this

```
_.uniq([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]);
// → [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It can also take advantage of the fact that the input array is already sorted. So, you might want to invoke it like this

```
_.uniq([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4], true);
// → [1, 2, 3, 4]
```